# How to stay logged in cross domain firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing my project and here is a deal: I'm having firebase auth email and password based. Then I've created landing for users and what I'm trying is to let users signup from landing which is on different domain and stayed logged in on my main app.
I've looked up firebase docs but didn't find any snippets. Basically I think there should be auth provider config, but again there is no info. Maybe you've faced such an issue, how you've solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot signup users on one domain and allow them to login into a different domain with those signup credentials. Firebase doesn't allow that. Each domain has its own auth setup that doesn't coincide with another domain's authentication. You can use sub domains if you want. ->
https://dev.to/johncarroll/how-to-share-firebase-authentication-across-subdomains-1ka8

You will have to create cloud functions but to achieve this even on subdomains.

Gist of that article.

> Getting Firebase Authentication to work across subdomains is not super
> straightforward, but it is doable without that much work.
> Unfortunately, you need to be familiar with a number of concepts such
> as CORS, cookies, JWTs, Firebase Authentication itself, etc.

Might as well develop your own Nodejs server instead of using hacks and workarounds like in the article.